# Show category posts in Laravel is not working

Tags: laravel

I want to show posts that are in a category by clicking on them, but when I click on a category,`$articles` in `category.blade.php` returns null.

`$articles` should return articles that have a specific category

this is my `index.blade.php`:

```
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="show-categories" role="tabpanel">
                        <h6 class="sidebar-title">Categories</h6>
                        <div class="row link-color-default fs-14 lh-24">
                          @foreach($categories as $category)
                            <div class="col-6">
                              <a href="{{ route('cms.category', $category->id) }}">
                                {{ $category->name }}
                              </a>
                            </div>
                          @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

`category.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @forelse ($articles as $article)
    <h1>{{$article->title}}</h1>
    @empty 
        <span>array is empty</span>
    @endforelse
   
@endsection
```

`router`:

```
Route::get('cms/categories/{category}', [articlesController::class, 'category'])->name('cms.category');
```

and `articlesController`:

```
    public function category(Category $category)
    {
      return view('cms.category')
        ->with('category', $category)
        ->with('articles', $category->articles()->searched()->simplePaginate(3))
        ->with('categories', Category::all())
        ->with('tags', Tag::all());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't forget to define the relationship from **Category** to **Article** on your model. Like: one category has many articles. For example:

On your **Category.php** model:

```
public function articles() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
}
```

Then on your, controller, you may call the relationship like this way:

```
public function category(Category $category)
{
    $articles = Category::with("articles")->where("id", $category->id)->simplePaginate(3);
    return view('cms.category')
        ->with('category', $category)
        ->with('articles', $articles)
        ->with('categories', Category::all())
        ->with('tags', Tag::all());
}
```

Comment: @S Ahmad Naim i do this but it shows only one article!

Comment: Yeah. As you have specified the `$category->id`, then it will fetch only one category belongs to that id. And on you can fetch the articles as like:
$article->categories()
Actually you have to iterate the articles as article and then the previous line would work.

Comment: I want to fetch all articles that blogs to a specific category

Comment: i can show that with this solution:    `$articles = Article::with("icategories")
        ->where("category_id", $category->id)
        ->simplePaginate(3); `

Comment: If you want to fetch all articles belongs to a specific category, then on your controller, write code like this:

$articles = Category::with("articles")->where("id", $category->id)->get();

Comment: @S ahmed Naim thanks 

Comment: Yeah. You are most welcome. @Mehrabt

Answer (score 1):

Please share the model file and second I prefer to write the category method in a different way.

```
    public function category($category_id)
    {
        try {
            $articles= Article::where('id', $category_id)->get();
            
            return view('cms.category', $articles);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            Log::error($th->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you still face any issue. Try to use dd $articles ..

Comment: @Mehrabt pleaes mention foreign_kye
return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'foreign_key');